# symfony2 doctrine decimal precision scale annotations are ignored

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, decimal, precision

i've set up an attribute in my entity like this :

```
/**
 * @var decimal
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=7, nullable=true)
 */
private $latitude;
```

but when i generate the database schema with : doctrine:database:create; doctrine:schema:create

my field is set up to decimal (10,0) in the database (when i look up with phpmyadmin)
and so, when in insert data like **42.123456** with a form, this data is truncated to **42**.

how can i resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic, but seeing your name makes me want to tell a Chuck Norris joke.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. When I run the command with your configuration, doctrine creates the field as decimal(10,7)

Comment: ok, on another computer, it works well, BUT when i wanted to change to precision and scale again, for example (15,8) it stays to the first precision/scale (10,7). Is there any cache somewhere? i tried "doctrine:cache:clear-metadata", "doctrine:cache:clear-query" and "doctrine:cache:clear-result" but with the same results

Comment: ok, its clearly a doctrine probleme, i remove the concerned attribute from my entity, run doctrine command, the rows correctly removed from database. Then i created them again but changing from decimal (10,7) to integer and them run doctrine with sql dump and here is what i get : **ALTER TABLE mytable ADD latitude NUMERIC(10, 7) DEFAULT NULL, ADD longitude NUMERIC(10, 7) DEFAULT NULL;**, WTF?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally get to resolve this.
Simply **manually** remove the cache (app/cache/..)

removing it by symfony command cache:clear **wont revolve the problem**