# Symfony2 entity returns float as smaller float then in db

Tags: symfony, numbers, entity, return-value

So I got this in my entity,

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Range(   min = "-180",
 *                  max = "180")
 *
 */
protected $longitude;
```

and when I do this in the `public function getLongitude()`

```
var_dump($this->longitude); exit();
```

this is printed

```
float 4.5003715
```

but in the database the value is

```
4.500371500000028
```

Can't figure it out. Any tips ?

---

Edit:

```
@ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true, precision=11, scale=8)
```

Changed to this, but remains returning

```
float 4.5003715
```

Comment: you could add `scale` to your column definition `@ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true, scale=15)`

Comment: Doesn't change anything :(

Comment: too bad, did you update the database schema after adding the line ?

Comment: I did. Then made sure the value was still long enough.

Comment: try to use `decimal` type instead of `float`, like: `@ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true, precision=11, scale=8)` Longitude ranges from -180 to +180 degrees so `DECIMAL(11, 8)` is enough. Remember to clear the cache when you modify annotations.

Comment: this answer points pout that a munal remove of cache may be necessary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194792/symfony2-doctrine-decimal-precision-scale-annotations-are-ignored

Answer (score 1):

`float` is a type with precission loss, change your type to `decimal` if you want to get the exact value. Something like:

```
@Column(type="decimal", precision=18, scale=15)
```

Comment: This causes a lot of 0's at the end of my numbers.

Comment: 0's at the end of your numbers do not change the "value" of them,
1.5 is equal to 1.500000000000

Comment: I used `precision=16, scale=15` based on your example number `4.500371500000028`. But reading your "assert range", you must use `precision=18, scale=15` if you want to store `179.500371500000028`. I updated my answer.